# How to implement a Try/Catch block in a form

Tags: vb.net

I have created a form for student-course registration that has three entry text boxes:

- Name and surname
- Phone number
- Address

I then have another text box that I use to display the student information.  I call this display-only text box the "course" text box.

I want to make use of structured exception handling (`Try`/`Catch` block) on this form.  How can I do that on this kind of a form.

Comment: Which exception do you want to catch?  Which line(s) in the code will be throwing the exception?  You shouldn't be catching exceptions unless you expect them to happen and you know what to do when they do happen.

Comment: I've got no idea of what  can be cached on this form, I'm just looking for some advices on what can be cached on a form under general, not only looking on textboxes that I'm having, but  a form under general

Comment: It's impossible to say, given the limited details and lack of example code, what exceptions may occur and on which lines of code.  If you are simply concatenating the values entered into the text boxes to display in the "course" text box, then there are no exceptions to expect from an operation like that.

Answer (score 4):

### Exception Handling with Try/Catch

Exception handling in VB.Net is very easy. The following code is the structure of the try/catch block.

```
 Try
       'This is the code you wish to try that  might give an error.
    Catch ex As Exception
       'This is where you end up if an error occurs.
    End Try
```

Lets say you have a button on your form and you want to make sure that after the button is pressed, all the instruction you have will be error handled properly. The following code illustrates. First drop a button and name it ValidationButton. If you double click your new button, in the code behind you will see a new function that handles the click event. Add the try catch block to it as seen below.

```
Private Sub ValidationButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ValidationButton.Click
    Try

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Now the page has a button and the code inside it is in a try/catch block. We simply put the  code we want inside. Lets put something that will throw and error, and then we will display that error.

### Example Code

```
Private Sub ValidationButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ValidationButton.Click
    Try
        Dim x As Integer = 1
        Dim y As Integer = 0
        Dim z As Integer = x / y
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

A message box pops up telling us that we encountered an error, "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow". This is ofcourse because we cannont divide by zero. If you had not placed this in the try catch, the program would have crashed.

So, with this information, put your try/catch in places where you could possibly have an error. If you know what your error might be, you can even have code in there to do something else. In our example, we might want to tell the user not to divide by zero.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to catching errors in  specific lines of code, you can also catch unhandled errors. This is easiest done by starting the application through the [Main Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235406.aspx)

```
Module Program

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf UIThreadException

        ' Force all Windows Forms errors to go through our handler.
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException)

        ' Start the main Form
        Application.Run(New frmMain())
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub UIThreadException(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                         ByVal t As ThreadExceptionEventArgs)
        ' Handle the error here
    End Sub

End Module
```

You can read more on this subject on MSDN: [Application.ThreadException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)